# Very Simple echo in PHP error

Tags: php, echo

i have try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php phpinfo(); die; ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>TRY IT</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "test";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It is very simple echo syntax in php. Output that should i got is string "test" on my screen. but output that i got just a blank page. 
For your information php version that installed on my computer is version 5.3.8
anyone know what happen?

Comment: Remove `die;` from the top of the page.

Comment: [_Have you enabled error reporting ?_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1003917)

Comment: @vee, That has nothing to do with blank page.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, it's not blank page, it's "black screen" :)

Comment: You sure your screen ain't off ? :) `phpinfo();` should work smoothly.

Comment: If `phpinfo` does not work then your web server probably is not configured correctly for php.

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran sorry.. I mean black page. so my browser just show the white page. there is should be string "test" on it, but it didn't show anything.

Comment: Your code worked for me --- Make sure that PHP is in fact properly installed and configured. Make a test page and put `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` see what that gives you. However, your `echo "test";` will never echo because of the `die();` so that needs to be removed if you want your echo to execute.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes i try `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` too but still didn't work. yes i think there is something on configuration. but i just install xampp i didn't change anything

Comment: It's a configuration issue then.

Comment: @Fred-ii- any idea to check the configuration?

Comment: Sorry I know nothing about setting up Webservers/PHP. I run all my stuff off a hosted service.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `die` on the second line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php phpinfo(); die; ?>
                 ^^^^ Remove this
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>TRY IT</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "test";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope that is not the issue. `phpinfo();` would still output.

Comment: that code i got from other thread that used to show error in php. but i got nothing. i have been delete that and i got the same black page.

Comment: @mas_bejo black page? as in the screen just goes black?? What happens when you view source?

Comment: Sidenote: `echo "test";` will not execute because of the `die();` so there is some truth to this answer.

Comment: @kamehameha sorry i mean blank page. so it just show white page. it should be a string "test" on it but it didn't.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have benn delete it but nothing happen.

Comment: @mas_bejo are other functions working? Probably the server might not have setup properly.